# How to expand and contract the height of div on click?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to expand and contract the height of div on click the description.I used

> **onclick="style='height:auto'"**

This code expand the div.I want to contract it as well.

```
<div style="height: 35px;" onclick="style='height:auto'">

      <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 15px;" >{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>

      </div>
```

**Current position of the page**
this is the view of current page where i set the height to 35px.

[image]

After i click on div, it expands the div.

[image]

**Requirement** I want to contract it also on the same click on div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html**:

```
 <div *ngFor="let list of lists;let i=index" (click)="toggleList(i)" [style.height]="isListExpanded(i)?'auto':'35px'">
      <p>{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>
 </div>
```

**ts**:

```
export class ClassName{

 shownList = null;

 toggleList(list) {
     if (this.isListExpanded(list)) {
         this.shownList = null;
     } else {
         this.shownList = list;
     }
  };   

  isListExpanded(list) {
     return this.shownList === list;
  };
}
```

Comment: i display the list.taskdesc using *ngfor. Its an array. i tried your code but it expands each value of array on click. I want to expand that particular value which i click.

Comment: Do you want only one div in the list to stay expanded at a time, like an accordion?

Answer (score 0):

try like below code

```
<div class="{{classHeight}}" (click)="onClick()">

      <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 15px;" >{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>

</div>
```

make two class

```
.small-height{
     height: 35px;
}

.big-height{
     height:auto;
}
```

when click class change

```
public classHeight: String = "small-height";

  onClick(){
       if(this.classHeight == 'small-height')
           this.classHeight='big-height';
       }else{
         this.classHeight='small-height';
       }
   }
```

Comment: This only expands the div, it doesn't contract the div on the second click.